# Access USB printer in CUPS container with udev rule for SYMLINK

Tags: docker, usb, udev, cups

I'm running CUPS in a docker container using the [olbat/cupsd](https://hub.docker.com/r/olbat/cupsd/#!) image (docker container is a requirement, I can't change this).

I need to be able to print to a USB printer, which means using the `--device` flag to expose the usb device to the container.

The physical path of the printer (currently) is `/dev/bus/usb/001/005` and when i pass this into `--device` the printer is listed as an available printer within CUPS.

The issue is when the device is removed, it gets allocated a new path - I attempted to use a udev rule to address this with a SYMLINK (see below).

```
ACTION=="add" SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{product}=="$Product", SYMLINK="bus/usb/001/009"
```

*where $Product is a valid product*

This creates `/dev/bus/usb/001/009` as expected, but when passed into the container using `--device` the printer is not listed under the available printers.

However running `udevadm info /dev/bus/usb/001/009` **inside** the CUPS container, lists the printer but with `DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/005` and `N: /bus/usb/001/005`.

I feel like this is very close to working, but something is missing.